# Raspbian Buster Keyboard layout menu in french

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I flashed a SD Card with the new version of raspbian buster and want to change the keyboard layout to german, but the menu is in french and most of the characters in the menu are just some black rectangles.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. To fix this you need to edit `nano /etc/default/keyboard`

Change its contents to:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```